# Difference between region of interest & viewport

Tags: video-streaming, viewport, roi, http-streaming, 360-virtual-reality

I am doing some research on adaptive streaming of omnidirectional video and wanted to know what the difference is between "viewport" and "region-of-interest." I've seen it used in the same context so I'm not exactly sure if they describe the same thing.

Comment: (How many "definition"s of *viewport* and *region-of-interest* have you come across, do you expect to be somewhat common, do you think to already have been used? If not introduced in *one single context*, I'd expect any demarcation to be disputable.)(I seem to remember *viewport* from EGS.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't think you will find any absolute definitions for these terms and ROI in particular is often used in different ways in VR.

I think the most common definitions are likely:

- Region of Interest - the parts of an image or scene which a viewer is most drawn to or most likely to focus on.
- Viewport - the entire view or video window presented to the user at a given moment.

So the viewport can contain one or more regions of interest.

It's gets more complicated if someone uses ROI to refer to the 'section' of a 360 video which is most likely to be of interest to the viewer. This is not the traditional meaning but I think it is easy to see how it might be used this way.